# Combining multiple lists to obtain integers for given condition

Tags: python, list, loops, cartesian-product

Let us suppose I have 3 lists with each of them has random numbers ranging from (0-9)

```
digit_0 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
digit_1 = [1, 2, 3, 8, 9]
digit_2 = [3, 4, 6, 7]
```

I want to create all the possible numbers for 3 -digit number `ABC`, such that `A` can only take values from `digit_0`, `B` can only from `digit_1` and `C` can only from `digit_2` arrays

The simplest solution seems to be creating 3 loops

```
for A in digit_0:
    for B in digit_1:
        for C in digit_2:
```

However, I am wondering is there a more effective solution ?

Comment: You have `tuple` not `list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

digit_0 = (0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)
digit_1 = (1, 2, 3, 8, 9)
digit_2 = (3, 4, 6, 7)

for digits in product(digit_0, digit_1, digit_2):
    print(''.join(map(str, digits)), end=' ')
```

Output:

```
013 014 016 017 023 024 026 027 033 034 036 037 083 084 086 087 093 094 096 097 113 114 116 117
```

It would be even better to put your tuples in a list, rather than giving them ressembling names:

```
from itertools import product

digit_choices = [(0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8), (1, 2, 3, 8, 9), (3, 4, 6, 7)]

for digits in product(*digit_choices):
    print(''.join(map(str, digits)))
```

and this will make it easy to generate combinations with any number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension, as an alternative to [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
digit_0 = (0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8)
digit_1 = (1, 2, 3, 8, 9)
digit_2 = (3, 4, 6, 7)
print([f"{d0}{d1}{d2}" for d0 in digit_0 for d1 in digit_1 for d2 in digit_2])
```

Output:

```
['013', '014', '016', ..., '896', '897']
```